# Create gopls.exe for offline Windows computer on a Mac

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up `Go` on my offline Windows computer, using Visual Studio Code. I have successfully installed VS Code, Go, etc., but am running into trouble installing the Go tools. Unfortunately putting my Windows computer online isn't an option.

The most important tool for me is `gopls` the Go Language Server tool that provides hover, autocomplete, etc., and will really boost productivity.

I have tried various things, including:

- Copying the binary file from `$GOROOT/bin/gopls` from my Internet-connected Mac to Windows.
- Cloning the `gopls` repo from Github and rebuilding `gopls` for Windows as covered [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling) by running `go build -o gopls.exe main.go`.

However I get the following error:

> Couldn't start client gopls

Copying the cloned repo to my offline computer and running `go install` does not work as there are other dependencies needed to fully build and install `gopls`.

Another tool, `staticcheck`, provides precompiled binaries for all platforms [here](https://github.com/dominikh/go-tools/releases).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a publicly available repo/mirror/site that provides ready-made, downloadable binaries for the main set of Go tools for Windows?
2. Is there a way that the Go tools can be built for a Windows OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug on this was setting the environment variable correctly.

To give exact steps:

1. Browse to your Go src directory: `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/`
2. Clone Go tools repo: `git clone https://github.com/golang/tools.git`
3. `cd tools/gopls`.
4. Run `GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o gopls.exe main.go` to compile a binary file for gopls that is compatible on Windows.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for each tool you need to install.

Ref: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling